# Übersetzung eines russischen Idioms, Wortlaut "Wo kam er auf meinen Kopf her?"

Tags: idiom, idiomaticity, russian-to-german

Ich tu mich schwer eine gute Übersetzung für ein Idiom zu finden. Im Wortlaut heißt es: *Woher kam er auf meinen Kopf?* Der Sinn dahinter ist in etwa "Wo kam er bloß her, jetzt muss ich mich mit ihm herumschlagen!".

Laut einem [Online-Übersetzer](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=3&sc=0&s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83&l1=2&l2=3) kann der minimal abgeänderte Ausdruck *den hat er mir auf meinen Kopf geschickt* mit *den hat er mir auf den Hals geschickt* übersetzt werden. Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das so stimmt, zudem weiß ich nicht, wie das auf die ursprüngliche Formulierung adaptiert werden kann.

Weiterer Kontext: Die Passage, einmal im Original (falls jemand DeepL o.Ä. nutzen möchte), einmal in wortwörtlicher Übersetzung und einmal in sinngemäßer Übersetzung.

Ein Dörfler ("Titus der Schwätzer") gibt eine präzise Wegbeschreibung, der Protagonist ist von seiner Intelligenz beeindruckt und denkt sich:

Original:

*И откуда ты, Тит Болтун, такой умный на мою голову взялся? И законы ты знаешь, и дедукцией владеешь, и с драконами на короткой ноге. Не селянин, а римский сенатор. Тит Клавдиус!*

Wortwörtliche Übersetzung:

*Und woher bist du, Titus der Schwätzer, so ein Schlauer auf meinen Kopf gekommen? Die Gesetze kennst du, die Deduktion beherrschst du, mit den Drachen bist du auf kurzem Fuß. Kein Dörfler, sondern ein römischer Senator. Titus Claudius!*

Sinngemäße Übersetzung (Vorschlag):

***Du bist mir ja einer, Titus der Schwätzer!** Gesetze kennst du, Deduktion beherrschst du, zu Drachen hast du einen guten Draht. Ein römischer Senator bist du, kein Dörfler. Titus Claudius!*

Comment: [Original and DeepL translation](https://www.deepl.com/translator#ru/de/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%09)

Comment: @infinitezero Aber so sagt man es im Deutschen ja nicht, oder täuscht mich mal wieder mein hinkendes Sprachgefühl?

Comment: Nein, es ist nur als zusätzliche Information gedacht.

Comment: Alles klar, verstehe!

Comment: Kann das Fragewort nur mit "Woher" übersetzt werden? Vielleicht auch eine Formulierung ohne Bezug zum Kopf: Wo kommt der den auf einmal her? oder Muß der ausgerechnet zu mir kommen? Ohne ausreichend Kontext ist es schwierig zu entscheiden, welche Formulierung am besten paßt. Vielleicht den Originaltext und die (unvollständige) Übersetzung hinzufügen.

Comment: Ich hatte die Hoffnung, dass ein einigermaßen nahes Idiom im Deutschen existiert, das mir bloß nicht bekannt ist. Aber nachdem das offenbar nicht der Fall ist, werde ich mehr Kontext hinzufügen!

Comment: Statt "mit den Drachen bist du auf kurzem Fuß" besser "mit den Drachen stehst  du auf gutem Fuß". https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auf_gutem_Fu%C3%9F_stehen

Comment: Der Abschnitt, wo "mit den Drachen bist du auf kurzem Fuß" auftaucht, ist ja die wortwörtliche Übersetzung, quasi das eingedeutschte Original, mein eigentlicher Übersetzungsvorschlag ist der letzte Abschnitt (direkt darunter), dort ist diese Stelle mit "zu Drachen hast du einen guten Draht" übersetzt. Oder wär "auf gutem Fuß" besser?

Comment: Wenn der Protagonist von Titus' Intelligenz beeindruckt ist, sollte "И откуда ты, Тит Болтун, такой умный на мою голову взялся?" etwas Positives ausdrücken - oder?

Comment: Ich denke, man würde so etwas einem vorlauten Kind sagen, von dem man einerseits beeindruckt, andererseits aber etwas genervt ist.

Comment: "auf gutem Fuß stehen" und "einen guten Draht haben" sind beide okay. Die Fuß-Variante ist näher am Original.

Answer (score 4):

Noch ein paar sehr freie Ideen zum Draufrumdenken. Ich kann allerdings auch überhaupt kein Russisch, das kann alles weit daneben liegen.

> Wieso tauchst du denn jetzt bei mir auf?

> Womit hab ich denn dich verdient?

> Wie hast du dich denn in meinen Kopf gesetzt?

> Warum spukst du mir jetzt im Kopf rum?

Comment: Der Ausruf soll Überraschung, idealerweise etwas Bewunderung und zugleich Verärgerung (weil der Bauer sich als intelligenter herausgestellt hat, als vom Protagonisten angenommen) ausdrücken. Der dritte und vierte Vorschlag nehmen den Kopf als Umschreibung von Geist oder Gedanken, aber so ist es im Original nicht, da ist der Kopf wirklich als oberes Ende des Körpers gemeint, auf das dann bildlich etwas herunterfällt. Beim zweiten Vorschlag ist die Verärgerung sehr stark, fast schon ein Überdruss. 1/2

Comment: Der erste gefällt mir von den vieren am besten, impliziert aber gefühlt zu sehr, dass Titus auch physisch zum Protagonisten gekommen ist, dabei war es aber in Wirklichkeit eigentlich anders herum... 2/2

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann kein Wort Russisch und kenne die russische Redewendung nicht. Daher ist meine Antwort ein wenig spekulativ.

Eine Redewendung, die möglichweise eine ähnliche Bedeutung hat, lautet:

> Wer hat mir (denn) den auf den Hals gehetzt?

Die Wendung »die Person A der Person B auf den Hals hetzen« bedeutet, dass man der Person A mitteilt, dass die Person B etwas getan hat, das den Unmut der Person A hervorruft.

> Du hättest Ede nicht in unseren Plan die Bank auszurauben einweihen sollen. Ich traue ihm nicht. Glaube mir: Der hetzt uns die Bullen auf den Hals.

**Anderes Szenario:**

Bernd hat in der Arbeit einen Fehler gemacht. Seine Kollegen wissen davon, aber der Chef nicht. Bernd könnte seinen Fehler innerhalb weniger Tage korrigieren, so dass seine Fehlleistung danach niemandem mehr auffallen wird. Aber schon am nächsten Tag wird er deswegen von seinem Chef zur Rede gestellt. Es ist nicht anzunehmen, dass der Chef den Fehler selbst bemerkt hat, er muss einen Tipp bekommen haben. Wenn Bernd wieder mit seinen Kollegen allein ist, könnte er zu ihnen sagen:

> Wer von euch hat mir denn den Chef auf den Hals gehetzt?

Comment: Vielen Dank! Das geht Richtung des abgewandelten Idioms, aber ich tu mich immer noch schwer damit, es auf das ursprüngliche zu übertragen, wo es ja niemanden gibt, der aktiv die Person jemandem "auf den Hals hetzt"...